# La première fille qu'on a pris dans ses bras

Tags: accord, participe-passé

> Jamais de la vie
>   
> on ne l'oubliera,
>   
> la première fille
>   
> qu'on a **pris** dans ses bras.
>
> — tiré de « La première fille » de Georges Brassens, 1954 ([paroles](https://genius.com/Georges-brassens-la-premiere-fille-lyrics), [vidéo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=femVWPqTkqI)).

Or un objet direct qui précède le participe passé déclenche l'accord sur ce dernier.

Ceci étant donné, pourquoi pas **prise** ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Il s'agit effectivement d'une faute, et pour être correct, Brassens aurait bien dû dire "La première fille qu'on a pris**e** dans ses bras".

Il est possible que Brassens ait choisi de dire "pris" pour des raisons de musicalité. Toutefois on peut douter qu'il s'agisse d'une faute intentionnelle. On trouve en effet des enregistrements postérieurs où Brassens a corrigé l'erreur.

On a par exemple [ici](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S9CMkaZk7y8) un enregistrement live de 1955 ou 1956, et [ici](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VsxgLIZnYg4) un live qui date apparemment de 1979, où on entend Brassens dire "prise".

Answer (score 2):

La règle que vous évoquez est juste mais pas toujours respectée (voire même de moins en moins respectée). Dans le cas précis de cette chanson, mais aussi en général dans les chansons de Brassens, il s'agit probablement d'une adaptation pour que la métrique du vers soit en accord avec la métrique musicale.

Comment: Théorie intéressante, bien que Brassens ne semble pas avoir des difficultés à entasser une autre syllable dans un vers. ;) La note sur la disparition de la règle est valable.