# How alive is object agreement in spoken French?

Tags: accord

As in every (I think?) Romance language, attributive and predicative adjectives decline to agree with the noun phrase they modify. This includes participles in periphrastic verb forms like reflexives or motion verbs which conjugate with *être* as the auxiliary; so it’s *il est allé* and *il est né*, but *elle est allée* and *elle est née*.

For the majority of participles (and quite a few other adjectives), this doesn’t really make much difference in speech because all four possible forms (masculine singular, feminine singular, masculine plural, feminine plural) are pronounced the same, except that for plural forms, *liaison* of the final *-s* will apply. For a minority of participles, it matters in all forms: *il a été pris*, *elle a été prise*.

Uniquely (I think?) among modern Romance languages, French has an additional rule that participles in periphrastic verb forms conjugated with *avoir* as the auxiliary must inflect to agree with the **direct object** if the object comes before the verb and/or is a pronoun:<sup>1</sup>

> Les trucs que j’ai fait**s** *vs* Les choses que j’ai fait**es**
> Je l’ai vu (= I saw him) *vs* Je l’ai vu**e** (= I saw her)

As someone who learnt French in school, I recall that subject agreement was taught to us from the very beginning – it is such an integral part of the language. Conversely, I didn’t learn about object agreement until my fifth or even sixth year of learning French, around the same time as we were taught the past subjunctive, and (I think) *after* we’d learnt the *passé simple*.

This has led me to treat object agreement as roughly equal in usage to the *passé simple* or past subjunctive, both of which are (in)famously somewhere between moribund and completely dead in normal, spoken French. But I realise I don’t have any real basis for this belief, and Google has been singularly unhelpful.

So my question in a nutshell is this:

##### Is object agreement as natural a part of spoken French as subject agreement? Or does it belong to elevated registers similar to the *passé simple* and tends to be ignored in normal speech?

To give an example, if I said, « J’ai pris ma clé, et je l’ai mis dans ma poche », would I sound perfectly natural (assuming there aren’t any other parts of it that sound unnatural, that is)? Or would it immediately mark me as a non-native speaker?

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> As a bonus question, which of these definitions is more accurate? Most of the time they overlap, of course, but is this always the case? I cannot come up with any contexts where a pronominal object can appear after its governing periphrastic verb, but would it be possible to front a non-pronominal object for contrastive emphasis without adding a repeated pronominal object, and if so, would object agreement apply there? E.g., « Mon père j’aime beaucoup ; ma mère je n’ai jamais connu(e?) »?</sup>

Comment: As always, I think back to [this question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/29112) where I learned that Georges Brassens, recipient of the Grand Prix de Poésie de l'Académie Française, slipped already in 1954 on the audible agreement that should have distinguished *pris* from *prise*...

Comment: @LukeSawczak Thanks for that parallel! I did look for similar questions, but couldn’t find any! The answers to your question would imply that I’ve not been totally wrong, at least, and that object agreement is, if not quite as elevated as the passé simple, then at least _less_ intrinsic than subject agreement, and possibly on its way out.

Comment: The proper use of object agreement separates the "men from the boys" (or whatever metaphor you like) in spoken or written French. If you are looking to work at a publishing house, or television broadcasting you better get it right. When that e  needs to be heard and is not there, an educated person would note it. It is not as fancy as past subjunctive or simple past. It is a different order of speech. Les décisions que j'ai prises, for example.

Comment: This is the kind of question that calls for one to refer to one's acoustic memory of spoken French. Unless you look in videos, the Internet will not yield great results.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I wouldn't say it's really "on its way out" quite yet. It's still quite jarring to hear "J’ai pris ma clé, et je l’ai mis dans ma poche", the gender distinction is pretty strong, we are really used to doing that distinction in spoken French today.

Comment: I had much more written out, but a browser crash wiped most of it out, so here's an abbreviated version without the bibliography: Various corpora have agreement rates of between 28 and 65%. Agreement is highly correlated to level of education but even university degree holders barely reach 2/3rd agreement. Other important factors are the audience targeted by the speech (public speech professionals such as politicians and journalist reach 78%, private speech professionals like middle managers or teachers 43 to 47%, and "normal" workers 30%); the auxiliary used (50% for avoir and 77% for s'être)

Comment: the nature of the direct object that triggers agreement (3rd person pronouns are much more likely to be agreed with than non-pronominal objects or 1st and 2nd person pronouns) and metalinguistics elements such as "salience" of the PP and whether many complement follow or not (speakers show more agreement if the PP ends a clause or when the verb is the focus of the sentence)

Comment: In short, it's highly variable in a way that suggest that it's a grammatical virus (an artificial rule learned in school and not fully mastered by the average speaker) but object agreement occurs at a much higher rate than something like the past simple that has fully disappeared from everyday speech

Comment: Every corpora I've consulted also shows a lack of subject agreement of around 10% for PP used with être, by comparison.

Comment: @Eauquidort Oh no, browser crash strikes again (exactly why I write answers in external editors now)! I would be very grateful if you would be willing to go to the effort of turning it back into a fuller answer again, because that’s exactly the kind of thing I was really looking for. One thing you don’t mention is whether you were looking at both phonetically distinct and phonetically indistinct forms – I would expect agreement rates to be lower for participles in _-é_, since the distinction is purely orthographical there in most cases.

Comment: @Eauquidort Une réponse plus détaillée devient nécessaire. Par exemple, si je comprends bien, vous dites que "2/3 des personnes avec une éducation universitaire seulement accordent le participe passé" (si je comprends bien?). Ce qui voudrait qu'un tiers ne le font pas, mais on voudrait des exemples. Peut-être s'agit-il de cas limites? J'ai du mal à croire que 33% des gens éduqués à l'université diraient: _J’ai pris ma clé, et je l’ai mis dans ma poche_ au jour d'aujourd'hui, par exemple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The question is more complex than it seems.

### Bases

[Here](https://la-conjugaison.nouvelobs.com/regles/orthographe/l-accord-du-participe-passe-avec-avoir-179.php) is what french pupils learn in school about object agreement. They refer to it as "accord pour les participes passé avec avoir", which translates to "agreement for past participles when associated with have auxillary".

- if the object comes after, then there is no agreement (ex: "J'ai pris ma clé": "ma clé" comes after "pris")
- if the object comes before, there is agreement (ex: "je pense aux choses que j'ai faites": "choses" comes before "faites")

If you know this rule and apply it consistently you won't have any issue communicating with french speakers.

### Details

But of course this rule is only an approximation, because in reality there are a ton of exceptions.

For starters, object agreement always happens when a past participle is used as an adjective (so, without *être* nor *avoir*):

> Une fois découpées en lamelles, les pommes de terre peuvent être ensuite frites dans l'huile. (here "découpées" agrees with "pommes de terre")

With avoir, the agreement only happens with a direct object, not an indirect one:

> J'ai mangé une tarte. (no agreement because the object comes after)

> La tarte? Je l'ai mangée! (agreement because the object, here is the pronoun *l'*, comes before)

> J'ai mangé de la tarte. (no agreement because the object comes after and it is an indirect object anyway)

> La tarte? J'en ai mangé! (no agreement because the object is indirect)

Pronominal verbs are their own can of worm that I won't detail here as I am not sure myself to have understood it correctly. Just remember it is weird.

> Jeanne s'est souvenue de son rendez-vous.

> Jeanne s'est permis de partir en retard.

If the participle is directly followed by an infinitive, there is agreement only if the object is the thing that does the action suggested by the infinitive

> Ma voisine, je l'ai entendue dire des calomnies à ton sujet.

> La calomnies, je les ai entendu dire par ma voisine.

There is an exception with the verbs *faire* and *laisser* which never agrees when followed by an infinitive:

> Mes élèves, je les ai fait courir un kilomètre pour les calmer.

In case of a *tournure impersonnelle*, there is no agreement:

> Combien d'essais et d'erreurs il a fallu avant d'arriver à ce résultat?

I haven't included all the exceptions here.

### Conclusion

There is serious support from [linguists](https://www.tract-linguistes.org/) to simplify the way those agreements work. Anyway the rules that I listed under "bases" are those that most people know and you will rarely encounter somebody who complains about any of the mistakes listed in "details".

Comment: Some of these I wouldn’t classify as exceptions, but contexts where no agreement would be expected: fully adjectival participles are not verbal, so ‘object’ doesn’t apply at all; indirect objects and other prepositional phrases (as in the example given) are functionally very different from objects; and in the neighbour example, _les calomnies_ are not the object of _entendu_, but of _dire_. But I was not aware of the exceptions with _faire_ and _laisser_, impersonal constructions, nor that there are exceptions for reflexive verbs.

Comment: Could you kindly use a cap for nationalities and languages? I cannot correct the word French in your text because it is only one word... I think it would be a great idea to talk about spoken and written French in this regard.

Comment: Hmmm _La tarte? J'en ai mangé! (no agreement because the object is indirect)_? Ce _en_ ne correspond pas à _la tarte_? Je dirais auss: _Jeanne s'est permisE de partir en retard._ et _La calomnies, je les ai entendues dire par ma voisine._ parce que _les_ est le COD avant le verbe - tout au moins je crois que c'est ce que j'ai appris.

Comment: @Frank: précisément, il s'agit de cas typiques où même les francophones tendent à "faire l'erreur". Pour l'exemple de la tarte "en" correspond bien à la tarte, mais dans le sens "manger *de* la tarte", c'est donc bien un COI.

Comment: En fait, je reprends ce que je disais, à l'oral, je dirais sans doute _Jeanne s'est permis de partir en retard_.

Comment: @AnneAunyme Oui c'est le genre de truc qu'on a appris une fois à l'école et qu'après on oublie plus ou moins dans la pratique - surtout à l'oral, qui est le sujet de cette question ("_spoken French_").

Comment: L'exemple de Jeanne est une exception liée au fait que ce soit un verbe pronominal et je n'ai pas développé précisément parce que je n'ai pas trouvé d'explication claire là-dessus. Pour celui des calomnies on n'accorde pas parce que ce ne sont pas elles qui disent (c'est ma voisine).

Comment: @AnneAunyme Je vois - j'aurais sans doute un doute, et je chercherais à ce moment-là une référence si j'avais à écrire cela. Mais à l'oral, on n'entend pas la différence.

Answer (score 4):

We wouldn't say *J’ai pris ma clé, et je l’ai mis dans ma poche*. We would definitely say *je l'ai mis**e** dans ma poche*. That object agreement is not optional or dying in spoken in French, and it's not restricted to some registers of languages.

Comment: Agree it is not optional or dying in spoken French, but not so sure about about register (level of education).

Comment: @Lambie Yeah, I can see the register question - maybe you are right, but the bar would be quite low, meaning, if you don't do that agreement, the assumption will be that you have a very low level of education, or just don't master the language very well at all.

Comment: I also agree that wrong agreements are shocking. However, there are some questions about maintaining this rule : [Faut-il supprimer l’accord du participe passé ?](https://www.capital.fr/economie-politique/faut-il-supprimer-laccord-du-participe-passe-1305536).

Comment: @Graffito À ne surtout pas mentionner aux enfants en âge scolaire - on se prend immédiatement dans la figure: "mais non! c'est pas faux ce que j'ai écris! C'est une nouvelle règle!" (histoire vécue)

Comment: C'est moi que t'as upvoté. :) [pardone-moi mon franglais]